# Javascript calls relative paths and not from web root

Tags: javascript, jquery, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I'm calling files within javascript from example Ajax or other functions, the javascript tries to call it relative to the current address, and not from the baseURL or root.

Example if I'm on domain.com/my-page/ and I try to call a php file using

```
$.post('ajax/class.designer.php', { action: 'getcard', cardID: id },
        function(data) {
            loadCard(data)
        }, "json");
```

it tries to call domain.com/my-page/ajax/class.designer.php, when I actually want it to call domain.com/ajax/class.designer.php .

Same with plugins such as CKEditor tries to call it's .css files relative to the current address.

The application is using mod_rewrite and friendly url's. Everything is redirected to index.php which is located in / and from index.php I then call the functions to display the page.

I've set RewriteBase / and I've also set baseurl in my HTML head to the root path.

Note: Everything worked fine when I was running it on my localhost. The issue started when I moved it to my live server.

Comment: put a leading slash `/ajax/class.designer.php`

Answer (score 3):

Put a slash in front of ajax ie `/ajax`. When you leave the slash off you're going to get the relative path, ie the path relative to where you are. To get an absolute path always start with a `/`.

Comment: Yes ofcourse I could put a / infront of my call. But as I said, this also mess up my calls within plugins such as CKEditor that is trying to call from /.

Therefore I'm looking to find the way to make all javascript run from my root page. It worked fine on localhost even down on subpages, so there must be something different or "wrong" since then?

Comment: @MarcusLind Then I'm not quite sure what your issue is. How would this call mess up something else? You will need to post more code or explain more explicitly the impact of using an absolute path in this context.

Comment: @MarcusLind: it sounds like you're having a separate problem with CKEditor. Maybe post that as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the answer above is that you could add a base tag in the head. This will tell the browser where to start all relative paths. With your particular issue, you would add:

```
<base href="http://domain.com">
```

This would cause any relative URL's you add to start from root.